# ROS Answers SE migration: rosnode kill

Tags: rosnode

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to kill all nodes in one command.
Now ,we can use
rosnode kill
1
step by step to end all the node .

but i want to use one command to kill all node.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237862/rosnode-kill/) by [ligang](https://answers.ros.org/users/26953/ligang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-06-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems the answer is out-dated.

In kinetic, you could simply kill all node with

```
rosnode kill -a
```

or

```
rosnode kill --all
```

And actually you kill roscore, you will not kill all nodes. the nodes will keep exchanging msgs but we cannot access the topics any more.

---

Originally posted by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) with karma: 710 on 2018-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2019-11-12**:
More up-to-date, better answer. I marked this as an answer (and gave +1 for the previous marked answer :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know if it is what you want to do but if you kill the roscore, you kill at the same time all nodes.

But if you want to kill all nodes without killing the roscore, you can create your own script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

nodes = os.popen("rosnode list").readlines()
for i in range(len(nodes)):
    nodes[i] = nodes[i].replace("\n","")

for node in nodes:
    os.system("rosnode kill "+ node)
```

I have written this script in python. I tested it, it works properly. You can modify it as you wish.
I want to notice that the node */rosout* will relaunch itself automatically after being killed by this script.

I hope it helps you,
lfr

---

Originally posted by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) with karma: 201 on 2016-06-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ligang](https://answers.ros.org/users/26953/ligang/) on 2016-06-24**:
thank you, It's best!

**Comment by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on 2016-06-24**:
You're welcome